# GKAgent won't move up

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a player entity represented by the blue square in the screen below. It has a GKAgent component and when I tap a point on the screen, it creates a goal for the GKAgent to move towards that point.

Everything works fine, and my GKAgent can move to wherever I tap EXCEPT if I tap any location in the space ABOVE the player (a point with a higher y coordinate value as compared to the player's location) ONLY on the first time.

This is even though my GKAgent can successfully move to a space below it (lower y coordinate value). Also, if my GKAgent is already moving elsewhere and I tap on a space above it, it moves there successfully. It only doesn't move when it's the FIRST action AND the move target is to a space above it.

The purple line represents the path and the purple node represents the end location I'd like the agent to move to.

This is super mysterious and is driving me crazy. Any ideas on what the problem might be?

[image]